# Cesium -- on click, change map point to standard marker with icon

Tags: javascript, maps, cesiumjs

I am attempting to mimic the the functionality one would see using the Waze LiveMap (https://www.waze.com/livemap) in Cesium. When a point is clicked, it is converted to a marker with an icon.

I've attempted a few different things with varying levels of success and I'm at my wits end. Does anyone have a good suggestion as to how I can proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple different ways of doing this, some high-level and some lower-level.  The high-level one is easiest so I'll start there.  The Cesium Viewer fires an event called `selectedEntityChanged` when its own selection changes, and you can wire that up to toggle billboard show flags on and off.

[Here's a demo](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/?src=Hello%20World.html&label=Showcases&gist=878dbe88549435a72819907f70cda3cb).  For this demo, I took the original [map pins demo](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/?src=Map%20Pins.html&label=All) and added some lines of code:  I turned off the `show` flags for all the billboards at the start, I added points to stand in for the now-hidden billboards, and I added the following block of code to toggle the billboard show flags when selected, like this:

```
var lastSelectedPin;
viewer.selectedEntityChanged.addEventListener(function(newEntity) {
    if (lastSelectedPin && lastSelectedPin.billboard) {
        lastSelectedPin.billboard.show = false;
    }
    lastSelectedPin = newEntity;
    if (lastSelectedPin && lastSelectedPin.billboard) {
        lastSelectedPin.billboard.show = true;
    }
});
```

This uses Cesium Viewer's own selection system, but toggles the billboard show flag to appear when selected and disappear when de-selected.

Alternatively, you can dig into Cesium's lower levels for finer control, but there will be a longer learning curve.  The [Picking Demo](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/?src=Picking.html&label=All) shows off several types of picking operations, including [`scene.pick`](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Scene.html#pick), [`scene.drillPick`](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Scene.html#drillPick), and [`camera.pickEllipsoid`](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Camera.html#pickEllipsoid), which offer various ways to detect what contents exist at a particular screen location.  Often these functions are called in response to mouse movements or clicks, or touch/pointer events, to see what the user is interacting with.